# How to manage Premium Account with Angular at the payment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, payment, meanjs

I'm creating a website with many roles.
In my model, user role is an array. So a user can stack more than one role.

Exemple :

```
user.role = ['artist', 'premium'];
```

In a user case, the user can create a project and pay at the creation. It's free for premium.

My question is:

What is the best practice for manage the premium role?

I thought about two ways for release this:

1. In my payment page, I check with `Auth.isPremium() === true`. But I think it's a very bad practice.
2. I create another route just for premium account. I will check the role during the route provider as :

   `$routeProvider.when('/project/:type', {
       templateUrl: 'app/project/form/form.html',
       controller: 'ProjectFormCtrl',
       access: {
           requiresLogin: true,
           requiredPermissions: ['premium']
       },
     })`

Am I wrong?

Thanks for advance !

Comment: the problem with doing it in Angular is that that's on the client side; anyone can simply observe the code and craft code to do what they want to do. This should be in the server side check.

Comment: Ok, so @GeorgeStocker, I send the informations to the serve side. It checks if it's premium. If not, I send a payment requirement. The customer pay and it valides the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did this :

The user ask a query with his data for create his project.
If the server response 402 (Payment require), the user has to pay for the publication.

```
  $http.post('/projects', fd, option)
  .then(function (response) {
    $location.path('/');
  },function (response) {
    if (response.status === 402) {
      $scope.payment = true;
      $scope.error = response.data.message;
      $scope.stripe.publishable = ENV.stripePublishable;
    }
  });
```

I check the premium account with a middleware

```
    app.route('/projects')
    .post(users.requiresLogin, users.hasCredits, //check if premium
        multer({ dest: 'uploads/'}), projects.create);
```

So I create another route for "pay and publish".
Pay is a middleware.

```
   app.route('/projects/pay')
   .post(users.requiresLogin, projects.pay, users.hasCredits, //pay and check credits
        multer({ dest: 'uploads/'}), projects.create); // done
```